# Regex to filter product model (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to filter out information of product line and product model from HP product description.

Examples:

```
HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF (H3S08US#ABA)
HP Pro 3400 Series MT (H3S08US#ABA)
HP EliteBook 8460p (H3S08US#ABA)
```

Expected output:

```
Production line: EliteDesk
Production model: 800 G1

Production line: Pro
Production model: 3400 Series

Production line: EliteBook 
Production model: 8460p
```

Here is what I have for now.

```
product_line = re.search('([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*)', model).group(1)
product_model = re.search('([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*)', model).group(2)
```

However, the output gives result of 800,3400 on the first and second example.

Is there any better way to filter out these info? thank you so much all in advanced

Comment: Is the line always exactly one word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With regex and split

You could just use :

```
"HP (\w+) (.*?) \((.*)\)"
```

Here's an [example](https://regex101.com/r/ILeEks/2) on Regex101.com.

```
import re

text="""HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF (H3S08US#ABA)
HP Pro 3400 Series MT (H3S08US#ABA)
HP EliteBook 8460p (H3S08US#ABA)"""

pattern = re.compile("HP (\w+) (.*?) \((.*)\)")


for line, model, serial in re.findall(pattern, text):
    print "Production line : %s" % line
    print "Production model : %s" % ' '.join(model.split(' ')[:2]) # Only the first two words
    print "Serial number : %s" % serial
    print
```

It outputs :

```
Production line : EliteDesk
Production model : 800 G1
Serial number : H3S08US#ABA

Production line : Pro
Production model : 3400 Series
Serial number : H3S08US#ABA

Production line : EliteBook
Production model : 8460p
Serial number : H3S08US#ABA
```

## Just with regex

If you want a regexp solution only, you could use :

```
pattern = re.compile("HP ([a-z]+) (\d+[a-z]?(?: \w+)?) .*?\((.*)\)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

## Just with split

```
text="""HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF (H3S08US#ABA)
HP Pro 3400 Series MT (H3S08US#ABA)
HP EliteBook 8460p (H3S08US#ABA)"""

for line in text.split("\n"):
    words = line.split()
    hp, hp_line = words[:2]
    hp_model = ''.join(words[2:-1][:2])
    serial = words[-1]
    print "Production line : %s" % hp_line
    print "Production model : %s" % hp_model
    print "Serial number : %s" % serial
    print
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was overthinking the problems.